# Chrome doesn't open links from third-party software

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, skype, chromium

I have weird problem, not latest Chrome, nor Chromium doesn't open links from third-party applications, like skype (I've tested on latest stable and latest beta versions).
It's easy reproducable, if I set firefox as default browser and click link in skype message it's open in firefox as new tab.
Same doesn't work if default browser is Chrome.

OS: Windows 7 64, I've already perform check for viruses and etc.

Comment: It works well if I switch chrome to default browser after fiefox was default. I still don't found what corrupted default browser and why don't it restore if I just click `make default` in chrome.